# How to engrave text without boolean modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

As the boolean modifier messes up my image texture and cannot re unwrap. I need to find another way of engraving my text.

Comment: Subsurf + displacement...don't have time to write an answer ATM...

Comment: If you can't reunwrap you are limited with tools in Edit mode which do not change UV layout (like dissolving instead of deleting, loopcut etc). If this isn't the best way for this case then it might be wise to add fake letters with height map and not change any geometry

Comment: How do I go about achieving this with a height map?

Comment: Have you tried the Boolean modifier or Mesh-->Faces-->Intersect (not as stringent)  Once booleaned, separate the inner mesh from the impaled object. This will take the outer mesh back to a near distortion-free state.  It's not perfect but with lighting, what distortion may remain can be concealed.  Other than that, masking the outer surfaces of the text so it appears to be cut into the impaled object, and yet still see the extruded text's inner surfaces might be another way to tackle this.  Masking doesn't touch the mesh at all.  Texturing the inner surfaces with bumping roughens them up also.